# How to access light and dark variants of React Material-UI primary and secondary colors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The Material-UI docs for React say that light and dark variants of your primary and secondary colors will be calculated automatically.

(From the docs: https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/)

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: '#ff4400',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
```

What I can't seem to find is how to access these colors for use in my components. After implementing a theme like so:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    secondary: {
      main: '#287a9f'
    }
  }
})
```

How would I then specify that I'd like a component to use the light variant of the secondary color? Something like:

```
<AppBar color="Primary.light" />
```

I could certainly just implement them manually as custom colors, but this seems to defeat the purpose of automatic calculation.

Wisdom much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create your custom theme pass it to [`ThemeProvider`](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider) like this:

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
...

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    secondary: {
      main: '#287a9f'
    }
  }
});

function App() {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Children />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

And [there are many ways to access the theme variables](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component), for example you could use [`makeStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) or [`useTheme`](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component):

**makeStyles:**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
 myComp: { backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light }
});

function DeepChild() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return <Component className={classes.myComp} />;
}
```

**useTheme:**

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function DeepChild() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return <Component color={theme.palette.primary.light} />;
}
```

Note that the `color` property of the `AppBar` component supports one of

```
["default","inherit","primary","secondary","transparent"]
```

So in order to override the color for an `AppBar` component, as in your example, you need to pass a custom class:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
 appBar: { backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light }
});

function DeepChild() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return <AppBar className={classes.appBar} />;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense; but when I try to implement it, I get the following error: 

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `color` of value `rgb(71, 145, 219)` supplied to `ForwardRef(AppBar)`, expected one of ["default","inherit","primary","secondary","transparent"].
    in ForwardRef(AppBar) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(AppBar)))
    ...

Looks like maybe <AppBar> doesn't allow light/dark qualifications?

Comment: @Andy the `color` property of the `AppBar` only accept one of the values in the list, I've updated my answer